# Xamarin.Forms.Map Error

Tags: xamarin, google-maps-api-3, xamarin.forms

I am facing the following problem after Installing Xamarin.Forms.Map plugin

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zza;  app.Android

Any solution for this?

Using Visual Studio 2017, Xamarin forms and Xamarin forms map version : 2.5.0.280555

I have two more images of NugetManager

[Xamarin forms Main Nuget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOF7P.png)

[Xamarin Forms Android Nuget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRwhA.png)

Answer (score 0):

- open solution folder. clear files in debug and release folder
- Then open Package Manager Console 
  (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manger Console)

1st step - type "Update-Package -reinstall" and run.

2nd step - type "Update-Package" and run

this whole process takes few minutes. after finished, clean and rebuild the solution.

Comment: can you send me the project?

Comment: hi @Supun Liyanaarachchi cant send. Its a client project. I will share screenshots

Comment: Hi I had to install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps to make it work :)